# MapStruct: How to make my method of mapping from Long to Object?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, entity, dto, mapstruct

I have an Entity and DTO for it.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class GroupParameter {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ID_GENERATOR)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private boolean common;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE_REPORT_ID", nullable = false)
    private TypeReport typeReport;

}

@Data
public class GroupParameterIdDTO extends GroupParameterAbstract {

    private Long typeReportId;

}
```

When I map from DTO to Entity I need to map Long typeReportId to TypeReport typeReport.

I try to do this so:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class GroupParameterMapper {

    @Autowired
    private TypeReportService typeReportService;

    @Mapping(target = "typeReport", source = "typeReportId", qualifiedByName = "fromLongToTypeReport")
    public abstract GroupParameter fromGroupParameterIdDTO(GroupParameterIdDTO groupParameterIdDTO);

    @Named("fromLongToTypeReport")
    private TypeReport fromLongToTypeReport(Long typeReportId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return typeReportService.findById(typeReportId);
    }
}
```

But I get error:

> Error:(23,5) java: Can't map property "java.lang.Long typeReportId" to "ru.watchlist.domain.TypeReport typeReport". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "ru.watchlist.domain.TypeReport map(java.lang.Long value)".

How can I map Long to Object by finding Object in Repository by Id?

Answer (score 4):

All methods which are used in qualifiers need to be accessible to the implementation class. Currently, `fromLongToTypeReport` is private. You should make it `package-protected`, `protected` or `public` and it would work.

---

On a side node, you don't have to use qualifiers for mapping between `Long` and `TypeRecord`. You can just defined such method and MapStruct would be able to do the mapping.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class GroupParameterMapper {

    @Autowired
    private TypeReportService typeReportService;

    @Mapping(target = "typeReport", source = "typeReportId")
    public abstract GroupParameter fromGroupParameterIdDTO(GroupParameterIdDTO groupParameterIdDTO);

    protected TypeReport fromLongToTypeReport(Long typeReportId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return typeReportService.findById(typeReportId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you build it? I am quite sure, that it doesn't working. How MapStruct will find source with name typeReportId, if you are only passing groupParameterIdDTO parameter.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't try the code I wrote. However, I am quite confident that it works. When there is a single source parameter then the name of the parameter in `source` is optional. You can directly write the properties from the source parameter (`typeReportId` in this case). Was this not working for you? P.S. I am the project lead and one of the MapStruct maintainers.

Comment: Got a point:)Your solution is more clear then mine below:)Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your code a little bit(change source value). MapStruct reads name of the parameters in map method:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class GroupParameterMapper {

    @Autowired
    private TypeReportService typeReportService;

    @Mapping(target = "typeReport", source = "groupParameterIdDTO", qualifiedByName = "fromLongToTypeReport")
    public abstract GroupParameter fromGroupParameterIdDTO(GroupParameterIdDTO groupParameterIdDTO);

    @Named("fromLongToTypeReport")
    private TypeReport fromLongToTypeReport(GroupParameterIdDTO groupParameterIdDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        return typeReportService.findById(groupParameterIdDTO.getTypeReportId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made it by qualifiedByName like this:

```
import java.util.List;
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { IdTranslator.class})
public interface GroupParameterMapper {

//...

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "typeReport", source ="typeReportId", qualifiedByName = { "idTranslator", "toTypeReport" })
    GroupParameter fromGroupParameterIdDTO(GroupParameterIdDTO groupParameterIdDTO) throws EntityNotFoundException;

//...
}

@Named("IdTranslator")
public class IdTranslator {

    @Autowired
    TypeReportService typeReportService;

    @Named("toTypeReport")
    public TypeReport toTypeReport(Long typeReportId) throws EntityNotFoundException {

        if (typeReportId != null) {
            return typeReportService.findById(typeReportId);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

I don't know why I should use @Named before a class(so this's done in the official guide) because without it this works well.

Comment: You shouldn't really need `@Named`. The problem is because of the private method. See my answer

Comment: I  got a error. It says "Field memberTranslator in com.darioxlz.bookings.application.mapper.in.BookingRequestMapperImpl required a bean of type 'com.darioxlz.bookings.application.mapper.in.MemberTranslator' that could not be found."